# Onchange triggered only once

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

In sale.order I made the field and I want when SO state changes this field will fill up based on current UID

the problem onchange is triggered only once when I create SO, but when I confirm it, ocnahnge is not triggered.

What do I miss about onchange ?

```py
user_prepared = fields.Many2one('res.users', string="Prepared offer")

        @api.onchange('state')
        def _onchange_state(self):
             self.user_prepared = self._uid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @api.depends('state')
this will call method whever state fields value change

```
    @api.depends('state')
    def _onchange_state(self):
         self.user_prepared = self._uid
```

Comment: same with depends

Comment: have you changed state after creating this?
what process have you done tell me

Comment: i create Quotationn and onchange works , my field get value from UID, at this moment my Quotation in state "draft" , after that i push send email button ant state changes to "sent, and ocnahnge not triggered anymore, after i push confirm SO button and ocnhange not triggered again

Comment: @api.depends('state')
    def _onchange_state(self):
        self.user_prepared = self._uid

    user_prepared = fields.Many2one('res.users', string="Prepared offer", compute='_onchange_state')


Try this